# How to store and use a pfx file in a linux container

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers, x509certificate2, pki

I want to store a pfx file in a linux container and use it in the dotnet core application that runs on the container. The aim is to use this file for signing stuff, not ssl.
I could do it via copying pfx to a certain folder in a docker file, then loading it in the application code. But I would use certificate store if my environment was Windows.
I'm wondering if we could use cert-store in Linux for this purpose, if yes how, and then get the pfx via thumbprint in the application ?

Comment: If my answer worked for you - please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *cert store* that Linux supports is the `/etc/ssl` directory ;-)
The preferred way to do it is to keep it in a secure folder in you Linux server and mount it into the container (ideally as read-only).

If you're using `docker-compose` then you can specify that a volume should be mounted as read-only (and yes - you can even mount a file as a volume) as [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3), the gist of it is:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./your.pfx
        target: /your.pfx
        read_only: true
```